# How does this code in C work?

Tags: c, struct, syntax

```
typedef struct {
    char a[6];
} foo;

printf("%d", (foo*)0 + 7);
```

Why does this print out 42?
How does this syntax work and what is foo* exactly?

Comment: Because 42 is the answer to all.... ;)

Comment: There is a problem with that code; the string needs a closing `"`.

Comment: It won't compile...

Comment: It can't possibly "work". Post a [MCVE].

Comment: `foo` is the name given to that struct, so instead of referencing it as `(struct foo)<var>` everywhere it's just `(foo)<var>`

Comment: This code does nothing. It will not compile. Once the necessary additions are made, it invokes undefined behaviour. Any answer is correct. Problem is: what is the question? Read [ask], provide a [mcve] and state your **specific** problem.

Answer (score 10):

This is the version of your program that compiles:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  char a[6];
} foo;


int main()
{
  printf("%d", (foo*)0 + 7);
}
```

The output if 42 because the size of the `foo` structure is 6. The expression `(foo*)0 + 7` (or its equivalent `&((foo*)0)[7]`) denotes therefore address 42 (0 + 6 * 7).

But actually `printf("%d", (foo*)0 + 7);` is undefined behaviour (even though the output will most likely be `42` on most platforms), because for printing pointer values (an address *is* a pointer value) you need the `%p` format specifier and you need to cast to `void*` (the C standard says so).

So it should be:

```
printf("%p", (void*)((foo*)0 + 7));
```

but then it won't print anymore `42` but something like `0000002a` which is 42 in hexadecimal.

Comment: Is this true? Is it not just casting NULL to a foo* pointer then printing the contents of the '(7 * sizeof (foo))' byte in memory...?

Comment: @CharlieScott-Skinner No, there is no dereferencing here. [Try it here](http://ideone.com/g0Xac8).

Comment: would you mind reworking/expanding on the next couple of sentences after the code block,, particularly the second one? I'm having a hard time following...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand what you are asking but this might help.

```
typedef struct {
char a[6] {7};
} foo;

foo myFoo;      // instanciate a foo object

printf("%d\n", (myFoo.a[0]) + 7);  // access the first element of the array in foo
printf("%d\n", *myFoo.a + 7);      // access the value of the first element's
                                   // address in the array
```